# How do I create an object based on the output of a Function in Power Shell?

Tags: url, powershell, browser

I wanted to:
1. In Windows, Determine the system's default browser
2. Pass the browser to a new-object definition
3. Open the browser and goto a url

### This is what works so far:

```
    Function GET-DefaultBrowserPath {
        #Get the default Browser path
        New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider registry -Root Hkey_Classes_Root | Out-Null
        $browserPath = ((Get-ItemProperty 'HKCR:\http\shel\open\command').'(default)').Split('"')[1]
        return $browserPath
    }

GET-DefaultBrowserPath
```

---

However, the only way I know how to open a browser and go to a url is:

```
$IE = new-object internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate2("www.microsoft.com")
$IE.visible=$true
```

and this does not work:

```
$browser_object = new-object -com $browserPath.application
```

nor does this:

```
$browser_object = new-object -com firefox.application
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 4):

The Start-Process cmdlet will open your default browser and navigate to the URL:

```
Start-Process $url
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$path = GET-DefaultBrowserPath
$url = "www.microsoft.com"
&$path $url
```